# Flash builder player source control

Tags: flash, apache-flex

if anyone can list which folders need to be excluded from a Flash Builder project when adding it to source control. E-g bin-debug folder which is automatically generated when the project is compiled should not be in source control and etc

thanks

Comment: You only need 'src', '.actionscriptProperties', '.project', '.flexProperties' and maybe 'libs'

Comment: @J_A_X you forgot 'html-template' (if it is needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three more:

- **bin-release** - with exported release build
- **.settings** - with your project settings
- **.metadata** - with your workspace settings